# Is assignment simultaneous to indexing valid?

Tags: javascript

I just discovered this line and I'm wondering if it's valid code. Please note that I don't wonder what it does - that's obvious. I just want to know if it's OK code, academically speaking (and by that I mean that its validity lies in compliance to a standard or at least a generally accepted practice). I know it works in the browsers it needs to.

```
target.src = urls[index = ++index % urls.length];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "valid"? Does it work? What is your specific concern?

Comment: Yes: the [assignment operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1) returns the value assigned.

Comment: Yes it's valid, it just assigns a value from `urls` to the `target.src` based on the given index, that is calculated inside the brackets, nothing strange about it.

Comment: It is also valid to use something like `if( ( i = 24 ) && i != 25 )`. Although completely useless in this particular example, this can be useful in loops like `while( i = getNext() )` when `getNext` returns maybe `null` or `false` if there is nothing left to get.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is madness or genius, but it's valid. I'm curious how it fits into the code it comes from though.

Comment: An assignment is an expression. You can put it wherever you can put expressions.

Comment: @Llepwryd I'll be happy to elaborate if you tell me what you'd like to kow exactly. :)

Comment: @Ian I believe that the well-recognized definition of *valid* in such context is that the code follows some standard or accepted practice. I stated in the body that the code works so I'm not clear what you're asking. Also, my concern is clearly stated in the question, so I'm not clear on that question neither.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I know you ask "I just want to know if it's OK code, academically speaking", but why didn't you say "follows some standard or accepted practice"? That's clearer to me. Also, you didn't explain what about it you are concerned about. I'm assuming you're worried about the `=` operator being in the middle of the line (when you normally see it on the left, assigning values). Explaining that might've helped. I know what you *meant*, but asking if it's "OK code" isn't a good question

Comment: @Ian Now I see what you meant. Actually, you're correct as to me not being specific on the "inner" assignment and perhaps I should've point that more clearly. At the same time (while admitting that the question has some room for improvement) I realize that there are more components that are less commonly seen so a general "wholeness" of the syntax is of interest. Having said that, I didn't use "follows some standard or accepted practice" because I didn't think of such a formulation. In fact, I find it very well-written and I'll make sure to try to remember to use it the next time. Thanks!

Comment: See edit. If that was the problem, I hope that the downvoter will change their mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes (more characters for validator)

Answer (score 5):

It's valid, but it's pathological.

The behavior is well-defined and consistent, but if we care about readability at all... :-)

Comment: Agreed. One-liners like these are interesting but can be a nightmare to debug (line-by-line analysis with breakpoints) and maintain. Just because you the author know what it means, doesn't mean your replacement programmer will catch on so easily.

Comment: To me it's perfectly readable. I think it's a nice line of code.

Comment: It's valid JavaScript, but it will not pass jslint (will result in "Unexpected '++'" and "Unexpected assignment expression").

Comment: @Griffin - seems perfectly readable to me to, if your replacement programmer does'nt understand simple incrementation and modulus, he probably should'nt be replacing you.

Comment: @strille from 746 bytes snake fame?

Comment: @Griffin - not sure about fame, but yes :-)

Comment: @adeneo "he probably should'nt be replacing you" is another way of saying "he can still replace you".